# Copy-Item not working as expected in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a subfolder of a folder to a destination folder.I am using the following command:

```
Copy-Item  C:\ABC\XYZ -Destination D:\ABC -Recurse -ToSession $CopySession
Cop-Item C:\ABC\PQR -Destination D:\ABC -Recurse -ToSession $CopySession
```

The result is looks like this:

```
D:\ABC
file1.txt
file2.txt
Folder1
PQR
```

Where the Contents of Folder XYZ are :

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
Folder1
```

But the expected result should be like this

```
D:\ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: using copy item, use robocopy instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "copy" the root folder of your tree (XYZ) you could just create it within the process.

```
Copy-Item  C:\ABC\XYZ -Destination D:\ABC\XYZ -Recurse -ToSession $CopySession
```

> Example 3: Copy the contents of a directory to another directory and create the destination directory if it does not exist. This command copies the contents of the C:\Logfiles directory to the C:\Drawings\Logs directory. It creates the "\Logs" subdirectory if it does not already exist.
>   - [Copy-Item Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Use robocopy where you can as it covers off all the requirements of copy item as well has handling junction directories and symbolic links.

```
# /s - Recurse
robocopy /s C:\ABC\XYZ D:\ABC\XYZ

# /s - Recurse
robocopy /s C:\ABC\PQR  D:\ABC\XYZ
```

Fixing the original code, the destination is wrong and there was a typo in the second copy-item

```
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory('D:\ABC\XYZ')
Copy-Item  C:\ABC\XYZ -Destination D:\ABC\XYZ -Recurse -ToSession $CopySession
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory('D:\ABC\PQR')
Copy-Item C:\ABC\PQR -Destination D:\ABC\PQR -Recurse -ToSession $CopySession
```